# How to convert fuzzy hash string to a file?

Tags: java, php, python, encryption, hash

I know file name , file extension and fuzzy hash of document .

Can i convert that hash back to file using any programming language

like java or php or python

Comment: You understand that hashing is (by its very nature) a one-way process? It doesn't matter what programming language you're using, one-way is one-way

Comment: Perhaps he didn't know, is it a good place to ask?

Comment: i was mislead by this forum. i though he is converting the hash to image http://thedigitalstandard.blogspot.com/2009/11/why-fuzzy-hashing-is-really-cool.html

Comment: Seems strange that after 115 questions you post such a low quality question like this and ask `why it was downvoted?`. It shows no effort, no tries, it lacks information and is both unclear and broad

Comment: You weren't mislead, you just didn't understand what the writer was saying, I quickly scanned through it and it seems the writer him self dont understand how message digest works, `look weeeeee I changed a byte with a hex editor, the image is the same but the md5 for the image is different. What a Sherlock

Comment: read that blog post again. The blog post is taking fuzzy hashes and comparing those. They are **NOT** taking a hash and converting it back to an image. Basically it's `if (abs(ssdeep(orig_image) - ssdeep(new_image)) < margin) { they're the same}`

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are uni-directional, so no.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function